# Replace Windows 10 Storage Spaces Disk

Tags: storage-spaces

I just bought 3 brand new WD Red's (10TB drives) and build a new storage space with parity.

After about a day 1 of the drives is reporting 100 Current Pending Sector Count and the storage space is reporting as degraded.

Now to fix this issue do i *HAVE* to put a new drive in first, then remove the old one?

I'm asking as those drives are not cheap and I rather just replace it at the store I bought it at instead of having to buy a new one and return this one again.

Comment: It depends on the amount of used storage space.  You are currently in a degraded state, you would have to remove the drive, to fix the problem.  The only question is do you remove the drive then boot the system and allow it to rebuild before you replace the drive or turn the system off and replace the drive (either way the system will rebuild).  What mode did you select, please edit your question, do not submit a comment

Comment: Which Windows version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[Storage Spaces Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11382.storage-spaces-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx)
and especially the section
[How do I replace a physical disk?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11382.storage-spaces-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx#How_do_I_replace_a_physical_disk)
lists these conditions:

- The storage space must be resilient and healthy (not a simple space).
  Running the following command should find that
  `ResiliencySettingName` is either Mirror or Parity and `HealthStatus` is Healthy:

  ```
  Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName PhysicalDisk1 | Get-VirtualDisk
  ```
- There is enough space on the other disks to contain the data on the replaced
  disk. If there isn't enough space, you need to add a new disk before retiring
  that disk, even just a temporary external USB disk (but this will be slow).
  You can check unused disks capacity by subtracting `AllocatedSize` from `Size`
  reported by the `Get-PhysicalDisk` command.

For more information about removing a drive, with screenshots, see:
[How to Remove Drive from Storage Pool for Storage Spaces in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/83777-remove-drive-storage-pool-storage-spaces-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but my space was already faulty as 1 drive completely failed, the FAQ wasn't clear if you have to add a replace disk first before you can remove the broken one.

Comment: According to it the criteria is the amount of free available space. A disk must be added if that's not enough.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I just tried it, removed the drive and put a new one in, it still sees the broken drive as broken, but it says that it can't find it. It also automatically started rebuilding the space after adding the replacement drive.